# Batch Script: Column of output from program to variable?

Tags: batch-file

I've written bash scripts before, but I'm a little confused about how to do this with batch:

I have a program that outputs:

```
aaa boo
bbb boo
ccc boo
ddd boo
```

I'd like to iterate over the first column, and perform an action on each string.
How can I do this is batch?

```
var=OUTPUT
for col1 in var
    echo col1
```

I can probably figure out the for loop part, but I don't know how to get the column of output stored as a string.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm looking for a solution written in BATCH, for windows.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which is it? Do you mean [tag:bash] (Unix) or [tag:batch-script] (Windows)?

Comment: @Matt Ball It's for batch-script, Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MS batch on can use FOR /F

Process an output of a command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A IN ('command') DO ( 
    echo %%A
)
```

or process contents of a variable:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A IN ("%VARIABLE%") DO ( 
    echo %%A
)
```

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is for BASH isn't it? I'm looking for BATCH (Windows).

Comment: It is bash. Your question reads: "I've written bash scripts before", so I answered for bash, sorry! :)

Comment: Put the echo statement in the body of the loop, and you have a good answer that the OP is more likely to understand. The 2nd set of code is true, but doesn't really relate to the original question - It may confuse more than help.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thanks!
Also, the actual program has more than one space between the columns;
so setting "delims= " didn't work; I removed that and it mysteriously did!

Comment: @user1464333 - The default DELIMS are `<space>` and `<tab>`. Perhaps those spaces you are seeing are really tabs, which would explain why removal of the "DELIMS= " option solved the problem.

Comment: @dbenham Ahh, that would make sense; thanks for the clarification!